# Any way to remove the yellow duck (help tooltip)?

Tags: feature-request

Is there any way to close the help tooltip that appears at the bottom-right corner of the screen ?

As I usually zoom in to make the text more readable, that yellow duck becomes bigger and bigger, and I find it more annoying than helpfull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes, wait a bit and then choose "I hate this duck"

From the Meta StackExchange question [Stack Exchange has been taken over by a rubber duck!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308578/352819):

> You can then either go for "I have another problem" which repeats the same thing over again or you could select "I hate this duck" so make the duck sorry to hear that and bid Goodbye,duck.

I tried it myself. You have to choose for example "No" when it asks you whether you have a microphone or not. Then it goes through some text like "Quack Overflow is listening" and "The duck is thinking about your problem". After "The duck is typing" you will hear a "Quack". Wait a second or two and it will give you the option to choose "I hate this duck", after which the duck disappears.

Comment: Really the duck shouldn't be here at all.... it uses magic to work and 'use magic' is not an acceptable answer on this site ;)

Comment: You can choose the 'I hate this duck' option even when you said 'yes' in the beginning